# Executing a SQL Update batch within a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

1. I'm loading an excel spreadsheet into a datatable
2. Running validation activities against the data to check for issues
3. If all validation passes, I will iterate through each row of the datatable and execute an UpdateTable stored procedure with parameters
4. I need to execute this as a transaction b/c I want it to be an all or nothing upload and on error to rollback the transaction

The problem is that the datatable will have anywhere from 10,000 to 50,000 rows and by cmd.executenonquery firing on every iteration is inefficient and takes longer than it should.

```
 Dim db As New PGS.DBConnection

    Try
        db.BeginTransaction()
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim ParameterList(24) As SqlParameter
            ParameterList(0) = New SqlParameter("ProjectID", ProjectID)
            ParameterList(1) = New SqlParameter("Discipline", row("Disc"))
           .
           .
           .    
            ParameterList(24) = New SqlParameter("User", username)

            db.ExecuteQuery("EstimateInsert", ParameterList)

        Next

        db.CommitTransaction()
        Return "success"
    Catch ex As Exception
        db.RollbackTranscation()
        Dim db2 As New PGS.DBConnection
        db2.InsertError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.Source, "Excel Estimate Processing", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
```

The DBconnection object is handles the using functions to open, execute, and close all things sql.  In this case giving it a stored procedure name and an array of SQL parameters

I don't have to shoe-horn a fix into this framework and if I need to rewrite the entire thing that is fine.

Is there a way to run a set a batch size of 500 and speed it up?  Let me know if you need any more code posted...thanks!

Comment: I would say try temporary table or create static table for this operation only and do it in one go from that table to target one than! So try split this operation into 2 steps.

Comment: B/c of error handling I can't do it exactly like this, but I decided to use SQLBULK Copy

Answer (score 0):

B/c of error handling I can't do it exactly like this, but I decided to use SQLBULK Copy